# Test-Path in local directory

Tags: powershell

Consider this simple path validation:

```
if ((Test-Path $_) -and ($_ -like "*.msi")) {
    $true
    }

else {
    Throw "Specify correct path to installer." 
    }
```

When passing a path e.g. `"C:\Scripts\installer.msi"` the validation works as expected.

But when executing in same directory as the installer, passing this argument as the path: `.\Installer.msi`

Validation is still `True` but breaks the installer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "breaks the installer"? It shouldn't matter whether you specify an absolute or relative path to an MSI, unless you're changing the working directory somewhere.

Comment: How is it breaking the installer? Are you hiding some code that is trying to execute the installer in some way? If it's returning true on .\Installer.msi then the script is working exactly how you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using msiexec.exe to run this installer, you have to pass the full path to that msi file in order for it to work.

So you're probably calling msiexec like this:

```
msiexec /i $_
```

when really you would have to do this:

```
msiexec /i "$((Get-Item $_).FullName)"
```

You might also want to look into the [MSI PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSI/3.2.26.21626). It makes working with msi files a bit nicer within PowerShell.