# Test-Path and msi files

Tags: powershell

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790681/test-path-in-local-directory) and noticed something I did not understand.

Consider this folder with one msi file and one txt file.  Why does Test-Path return false for the msi files? I am expecting $True for both test-path cmdlets because those files are in the folder.

```
$fldr = 'C:\AMD\WU-CCC2\ccc2_install\CN\amddvr\amddvr64'
$file = 'eval.msi'
$fullPath = Join-Path -Path $fldr -ChildPath $file

Write-Host '   Testing Path to ' $fullPath

Set-Location -Path $fldr
    Test-Path  -LiteralPath $fullPath


set-location -Path c:\
    Test-Path  -LiteralPath $fullPath 


$file = 'me.txt'
$fullPath = Join-Path -Path $fldr -ChildPath $file

Write-Host '   Testing Path to ' $fullPath

Set-Location -Path $fldr
    Test-Path  -LiteralPath $fullPath

set-location -Path c:\
    Test-Path  -LiteralPath $fullPath
```

this is the output

```
   Testing Path to  C:\AMD\WU-CCC2\ccc2_install\CN\amddvr\amddvr64\eval.msi
False
False
   Testing Path to  C:\AMD\WU-CCC2\ccc2_install\CN\amddvr\amddvr64\me.txt
True
True
```

As Requested in the comments:

```
ls $fldr
ls $fldr | % { '-{0}-' -f $_.name }
```

Returns the following:

```
Directory: C:\AMD\WU-CCC2\ccc2_install\CN\amddvr\amddvr64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                              
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                              
-a----        9/27/2017   3:03 PM        8945664 amddvr64.msi                                                                                                                      
-a----       10/17/2017   6:21 AM              6 me.txt
```

and

```
   -amddvr64.msi-
   -me.txt-
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please check the output of `ls $fldr` and `ls $fldr | % { '-{0}-' -f $_.name }` to see if the files are actually there and the names are what you expect.

Comment: It's pulling `amddvr64.msi` with the `ls` command, but you're checking for `eval.msi`?

Comment: yes that is it. I was using the file name posted on the other SE question. All is well again in the universe.